# **kwargs in Python

Tags: python-2.7, keyword-argument

So I was trying out the *args and **kwargs in Python. But I get an error that I cannot understand the reason of.

```
def new(a,b,c):
  print a,b,c

a={'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}
b={'1':7, '2':8, '3':9}

new(**a)
new(**b)
```

The new(**a) prints the results as expected, that is, the keys, 7,8,9. 
But, new(**b) gives the error:

```
new(**b)
TypeError: new() got an unexpected keyword argument '1'
```

Could anyone explain this? I am passing string as an argument in both cases, but 'a' works and '1' doesn't.

Comment: Variables cannot be numbers, which means your dictionary keys should not start with one.

Comment: If you think about the fact that `new(**a)` is essentially `new(a=7, b=8, c=9)`, you can probably figure out why it does not work.

Comment: @Nicarus There are two problems here.  That is definitely one, but that's not what Python is choosing to raise as the error.

Comment: The function you defined doesn't (and couldn't possibly) take arguments named `1`, `2`, or `3`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for Python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple. When you pass a dictionary to a python function as **kwargs it unpacks that and uses the keys in the dictionary as the names of the variables and you can **only use parameter names that you have specified in the function parameters list**.

Comment: I'd like to clarify that it is not just that the OP used numbers.  This would have still failed if they tried to use the keys 'd', 'e', and 'f'.

Comment: See my answer - you *can* have numeric `kwargs`

Comment: Actually @LegoStormtroopr, I am refering the **keys**, not the **values**. and the user did in fact not send number **keys** but stings of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

for a dictionary `data={"key1":val1, "key2":val2, ..., "keyn":valn}` when you do dictionary unpacking in a function call, `fun(**data)`, is equivalent to doing `fun(key1=val1, key2=val2,..., keyn=valn)` and this will success as long as your function had arguments key1,...,keyn and/or accept keyword arguments.

So the problem with `new(**b)` is that is trying to do `new(1=7,2=8,3=9)` which is a nonsense as the function only had arguments named `a`,`b`,and `c`, therefore the error.

For your, your second example try with list instead

```
b=[7,8,9]
new(*b)
```

Also, you may want to play around with this function

```
def test(*argv, **kwarg):
    print "positional arguments", argv
    print "key word arguments", kwarg
```

like for instance

```
test(1,23,42)
test(w=3,r="buu")
test(1,2,3,q=23,ans=42)
a=[143,56,76]
b={'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}
test(*a,**b)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is related to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters), but in short passing `**kwargs` to a method is a way to pass in a number of **k**ey **w**ord **arg**uments as a dictionary.

The reason your attempt fails is that your method new defines 3 named arguments - `a,b,c` so if you pass in a `kwargs` dictionary it *must* have these values as keys.

Its important to note that you can also *catch* `kwargs` in the method so you can call a method with numeric arguments, like so:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    print kwargs

a={'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}
b={'1':7, '2':8, '3':9}

foo(**a)
foo(**b)
```

Gives:

```
{'a': 7, 'c': 9, 'b': 8}
{'1': 7, '3': 9, '2': 8}
```